# Store listbox item based on index to a variable

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I would like to get the `item` in my `listbox` based on the `index` and store it to a `variable`.

**For example:**

Listbox_Sample

cary

bondoc

stack

overflow

If I want to get the index 0 of my listbox then it will store `cary` to a variable

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick. `Listbox_Sample.Items(Index #)`

**Example:**

```
Dim LB_Variable AS String = Listbox_Sample.Items(0)
Console.Writeline(LB_Variable)
'it will output the following
'cary
```